# How does this FileReader get "closed"?

Tags: java

Consider the following sequence of events

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException {

    FileReader f = new FileReader(a[0]);

    System.out.println(f.ready()); // true

    doSomethingWithReader(f);

    System.out.println(f.ready()); // false
}

private static String doSomethingWithReader(FileReader reader) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return line;
}
```

FileReader is not closed anywhere, but what closes it?

Comment: The wrapped BufferedReader will close it when it closes as the behavior of the close method is to propagate up the wrapper tree.

Comment: BufferedReader closes it. Interestingly, this isn't at all clear from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close%28%29) for `close()`, which says "releases any system resources", but doesn't elaborate...

Comment: @DNA Exactly :) I looked at the `BufferedReader` javadoc but could not make the connection until after i started debugging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you wrap a `FileReader` (or any `Reader`) with a `BufferedReader`, calling `.close()` on the `BufferedReader` will close the wrapped/underlying `FileReader` as well.

This is true of all the standard Reader, Writer, OutputStream, and InputStream classes that can be used as wrappers.

Answer (score 3):

```
br.close();
```

closes your reader.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [implementation of BufferedReader](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html): [open jdk7 implementation]

```
public  void close() throws IOException 

{
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (in == null)
                return;
            in.close();
            in = null;
            cb = null;
        }
}
```

It takes care of `close()`ing the underlying `FileReader` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the `BufferedReader` also closes the `Reader` it wraps, so in this case that's the `FileReader`.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block executes regardless of whether an exception is thrown. In your finally block, you close the buffered reader which wraps your file reader. Closing the buffered reader will close all underlying streams, including the stream used by your file reader.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc of BufferedReader, FileReader used to construct br also gets closed when you close br (in the finally block).

Comment: Although correct, I don't think the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close%28%29) says this, at least not very clearly...